# Angular2 "Services" how to @inject one service into another (singletons)?

Tags: angular

How would I go about injecting one service into another? Let's for example say I have a Collection that requires another Collection (TeamCollection => PlayerCollection). Currently I just create two separate Collections and use something like:

```
import {PlayerCollection} from "<<folder>>/player";
```

But this requires me to write my own singleton getInstance code within Typescript for each and every service that I want to be a singleton instance.

What is the correct way to do this? I want to have both singletons within my Components and be able to @Inject one service into another using the constructor syntax, without creating a new instance of the singletons.

```
class TeamCollection {    
    constructor(@Inject(PlayerCollection): PlayerCollection) {}
}
```

Answer (score 16):

So after re-reading this excellent post by Pascal Precht: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html

And seeing him comment on: http://twofuckingdevelopers.com/2015/04/angular-2-singleton-service/

"Everything injected using Angular 2’s DI is already a Singleton. No need for such a service"

I went testing, and what I now found has both answered my question and made me even more confused about the topic of DI in angular2.

See the following code:

team.ts

```
import {BaseCollection, BaseModel} from "./base";
import {PlayerCollection} from './player';
import {Injectable, Inject} from "angular2/angular2";

@Injectable()
export class TeamCollection extends BaseCollection {
    playerCollection: PlayerCollection;
    constructor(@Inject(PlayerCollection) playerCollection: PlayerCollection) {
        super();
        this.playerCollection = playerCollection;
    }

    create(data: Object): TeamModel {
        return new TeamModel(data);
    }
}
```

player.ts

```
import {BaseCollection, BaseModel} from "./base";
import {Injectable} from "angular2/angular2";

@Injectable()
export class PlayerCollection extends BaseCollection {
    create(data: Object): PlayerModel {
        return new PlayerModel(data);
    }
}
```

team.spec.ts

```
/// <reference path="../../typings.d.ts" />

//VERY IMPORTANT TO ALWAYS LOAD THESE
import 'zone.js';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'es6-shim';

import {TeamModel, TeamCollection} from "../../app/model/team";
import {PlayerCollection} from "../../app/model/player";
import {Inject, Injector} from "angular2/angular2";

describe('TeamCollection', () => {
  var teamCollection: TeamCollection;
  var playerCollection: PlayerCollection; 
  beforeEach(() => {
      var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
        TeamCollection,
        PlayerCollection
      ]);
      teamCollection = injector.get(TeamCollection);  

      var injectorT = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
        PlayerCollection
      ]);
      playerCollection = injector.get(PlayerCollection);
  });

  it('should have a singleton PlayerCollection shared between all classes within the application', () => {
    console.log(teamCollection.playerCollection.uuId);
    console.log(playerCollection.uuId);
  });  
});
```

As long as it was the same Injector (`var injector`) that created both they share the same uuID Though when I use a second injector (`var injectorT`) the UUIDs are different meaning a new instance is created of the playerCollection.

Now my question would be. If I use the component providers syntax:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  providers: [TeamCollection]
}) 

@Component({
  selector: 'player-list',
  providers: [PlayerCollection]
})
```

Would both share the same player collection or would both create a new instance?

Edit: 
**They do as long as they are created through the `bootstrap(.., [ServiceA,ServiceB])` method.**

Thanks to pascal precht http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html

Comment: So.. Any idea how to use the service within the other service once you've used Http to create metadata? I tried his example that's in the link at the bottom, but I don't understand how that injects the service into another service, or how you use it.. Confusing stuff.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz If you mean how you are supposed to inject one service into another after you have added it to the bootstrap method. That is quite simple if you use Typescript. You simply put it in the constructor for example: ''constructor(private http: Http) { }"

Comment: Ye I tried that, but the service always ended up being an empty object despite the injected service containing loads of functions. Not sure why. I also feel like there must be a cleaner way of injecting services into another service than the bootstrap method. The bootstrap method will become messy really quick, which seems odd.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz i can take a look if you provide an example. As normally there should be no reason why adding a service to the bootstrap method will not result in it becoming available to other services. There is besides this only one other way to get services and that is by creating your own Injector https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Injector-class.html but like i showed above this means services are no longer singleton.

Comment: I tried injecting my own service into another even after bootstrapping the dependency service with no luck. It worked with Http so I don't have to provide it within each component, but when I tried it with a service I created, no such luck. Mind taking a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649401/no-provider-for-service-error-even-though-it-is-bootstrapped

Comment: any resolution on this?  I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @Schippie - the documentation provided is no longer available.  are you able to achieve this mythical singleton service that is shared across services (and not components)

Comment: @george To have one service (`@Injectable`) available across your entire application simply add it to the `providers`of the NgModule (AppModule): https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#providers

https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview (see app/app.module.1b.ts)

Answer (score 1):

I found that another way of having a singleton service is by creating the singleton pattern with a getInstance() method that calls the constructor, then you don't inject your service to the component constructor, but just reference it as a static class.  You can check sample code in here:

[Access key data across entire app in Angular 2 & Ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815478/access-key-data-across-entire-app-in-angular-2-ionic-2/36897300#36897300)

Look for my answer, I think its the second in the page.  If it works for you I would appreciate if you could up-vote it. Thanks.

Comment: That's an anti-pattern :-/

Comment: I would advice against using a standard singleton pattern indeed (At least when we are talking about angular services) If you decide to build a service you use within other projects besides angular you can of course go down this route as well.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to make sure of is the following:

You can only inject the service once you have "provided" the service. When doing this in a @component its easy because you have the providers [ .... ] statement.

When you want to do this for a service you do not have the providers:[].... so the only place you can do this is during bootstrap time where you need to specify the service in

```
boostrap(app, [

PlayerCollection,
Other,
More Services...



]
```

If you dig in the documentation it specifically says you need to do it this way.

Comment: i have found that your suggestion does not properly address the question.  Can you specifically point to the documentation and provide a search string to query the page for?