# Transfer data between classes on click Angular 2/ Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

In my `app.html` I have a side menu that contains a list of roles. The toolbar on top of the app is a part of my `landingPage.html` and shows "App Name: Role" as the header. I'd like it so that whenever the user clicks a new role, it is reflected in the tool bar for the landing page.

I have a `changeRole(newRole)` function in my `landingPage.ts` file that would do that, but I don't know how to access it from the click event in my `app.ts`.

How do I listen for the event and then send whatever gets clicked to a function in a different class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of how to inject a service to share data globally from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37142598/1016128):

---

Using a provider to hold global data is working for me in Ionic 2 beta 6, and I believe it is the recommended practice in Angular 2.

Generate a provider from the command line: `ionic g provider GlobalService` Notice how the generated service is decorated with `@Injectable`

Inject your service in the `@App` class; you do this by declaring it in the providers array:

```
  @App({
        templateUrl: 'build/app.html',
              providers: [GlobalService] ,
              config: {} // http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/
            })
```

**This will create an single instance of your provider that is accesible on every page**. Wherever you need to use it, **do not** declare in the providers array, but on the constructor of the Page:

```
@Page({
        templateUrl: 'build/pages/new-page/new-page.html',
      })
      export class NewPage{

       constructor(public globalService: GlobalService) {
    }

    someFunction(){
    this.globalService.someGlobalFunction();
    }
```

Comment: Do i still need to import the Global service in my page file? I'm getting an error if I don't try, but if I do try to import it, it can't seem to find the file. Am I missing an obvious step in dependency injection? i'm still pretty new at this.

Comment: Yes, you need to import it, with a line like this: 
`import {GlobalService} from '../../providers/global-service/global-service'`, you need to adjust it for the right path in your app

Comment: I'm missing 1 part. When I see the change in roll on the app side menu, I call my `setCurrentRole` function in the `GlobalService`, but how do I then notify the "new page" that the currentRole has been changed?

Comment: You dont have to. Let's say roleName is the variable in your service that is updated by the setCurrentRole function. In your page template you just put {{globalService.roleName}} where you want the role name to appear, and it will update every time you change it

Answer (score 2):

There's a good resource here that details some common patterns for component interaction:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

For your use case, you'll probably want to define a service to encapsulate your 'role' value.  Inject that service into components that need to access that value.