# How can I change ion-title programmatically in Ionic2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

In my Ionic2 project I have tabbed view with three tabs:

**tabs.ts**

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
    <ion-title>My tab parent title</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabIcon="people"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabIcon="person"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabIcon="globe"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Does anyone know how I can programmatically change the `ion-title` of this page from one of the child tabs?

Comment: Maybe you could use a provider to store a "global variable," which could be modified from any page where the provider is injected. See this article: https://ionicallyspeaking.com/2016/03/10/global-variables-in-ionic-2/

Comment: since two people have given responses and you have stated that it is not what you are looking for, I might suggest you do a better job of asking the question because it doesn't appear to be very clear.

Answer (score 8):

I did it this way:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>{{title}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tabLogin" tabTitle="Login" tabIcon="log-in" (ionSelect)="this.title ='Login'"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tabSignup" tabTitle="Sign up" tabIcon="add-circle" (ionSelect)="this.title ='Sign up'"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Took me forever to find a good answer like this.

Answer (score 2):

see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37142598/1016128) on how to use a provider to share data between different pages: in your tabs template use a variable that you store in the provider `<ion-title>{{globalService.titleName}}</ion-title>` , and in your tab pages just modify the value of `globalService.titleName`

---

Using a provider to hold global data is working for me in Ionic 2 beta 6, and I believe it is the recommended practice in Angular 2.

Generate a provider from the command line: `ionic g provider GlobalService` Notice how the generated service is decorated with `@Injectable`

Inject your service in the `@App` class; you do this by declaring it in the providers array:

```
  @App({
        templateUrl: 'build/app.html',
              providers: [GlobalService] ,
              config: {} // http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/
            })
```

**This will create an single instance of your provider that is accesible on every page**. Wherever you need to use it, **do not** declare in the providers array, but on the constructor of the Page:

```
@Page({
        templateUrl: 'build/pages/new-page/new-page.html',
      })
      export class NewPage{

       constructor(public globalService: GlobalService) {
    }

    someFunction(){
    this.globalService.someGlobalFunction();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not really what I am looking for. I need to define the title in the "parent" page of all tabs. Not in the tabpage itself. The reason for this is the parent page has some buttons e.g. search, and some other actions which need to be available in all the tabs. Therefore the tabs do not have a navbar defined.

Comment: so? this has nothing to do with navbars or not; any page where you inject the service can access `globalService.titleName`. You can change it from you tabs and use it in your parent template.

Comment: Well this is not what I wanted. I need to define the title in the "parent" page of all tabs. Not in the tabpage itself or in a service.

Comment: yeah, you need to clarify what you want, or point out what you don't understand about this answer, because I believe it's the right way to do what you want.

Comment: I want either in the template of `tabs.ts` as shown in my question to define the titles for each child tab, or programmatically in `tabs.ts`

Answer (score 2):

Import app and add it as a constructor

```
import { App } from 'ionic-angular';

 constructor(private app: App ) { }
```

then add event handler on enter page

```
  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.app.setTitle('people');
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are good answers, and thought-provoking, but the **official** recommended way to set the document title in Ionic is to use Angular's `Title` Component:

In app.module:

```
import { Title }  from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
...
  providers: [
    Title
  ],
```

Somewhere else:

```
import { Title }     from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class SomeComponent {
  public constructor(private titleService: Title ) { }

  public someMethod(){
    this.titleService.setTitle ('An Awesome Title');  
  }
```

Reference: https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title

Please note that @LeRoy's answer is technically correct!  I.e. per Ionic's official docs it should *totally* work!  And it used to!  But it doesn't anymore!  And what's more is [app.setTitle (not working) is a known issue in Ionic 2+](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/13436#issuecomment-355168616) that will ONLY be fixed in the next major release of the framework (v4).

Comment: I'm using version 3+ and it works ! thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 0):

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#tabs

have you tried to just create the ion-navbar in the specific page

```
@Page({
  template: `
    <ion-navbar *navbar>
      <ion-title>Heart</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
    <ion-content>Tab 1</ion-content>`
})
class Tab1 {}
```

Comment: Yes, but is not what I wanted. I need to define the title in the "parent" page of all tabs. Not in the tabpage itself.