# Ionic2 ion-slides change navbar title

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm trying to change the navbar title using the slides.
When swiping through a next slide, how can I achieve this?
I tried:

```
onSlideChangeStart(slider) {
this.app.setTitle('title1');
}
```

But it just sets the title in the browser, not in the ion-title tag.
And I want to set the title according to the slide that is displaying.

This is my code:

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar color="navh" no-border-bottom>
<ion-title>title</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content  no-bounce >
<ion-slides [options]="mySlideOptions (ionWillChange)="onSlideChangeStart($event)">

<ion-slide>
     <img #title1 src="assets/img/1.png" >
</ion-slide>
<ion-slide>
     <img #title2 src="assets/img/2.png" >
</ion-slide>
<ion-slide>
     <img #title3 src="assets/img/3.png" >
</ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change ion-title programmatically in Ionic2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471612/how-can-i-change-ion-title-programmatically-in-ionic2)

Answer (score 0):

What about using a variable to set the title?

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl:"home.html"
})
export class YourAwesomePage {
  @ViewChild('mySlider') slider: Slides;

  public title: string;
  // ...

  constructor() {
    this.title = 'Initial title';
    // ...
  }

  onSlideChangeStart(slide) {
    // You can use the slide parameter to get info from it or just use the slider reference to know the index of the active slide
    let currentIndex = this.slider.getActiveIndex();
    this.title = "Slider " + currentIndex;
  }
}
```

And then in your view:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="navh" no-border-bottom>
    <ion-title>{{ title }}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content no-bounce >
  <ion-slides #mySlider [options]="mySlideOptions" (ionWillChange)="onSlideChangeStart($event)">

    <ion-slide>
      <img #title1 src="assets/img/1.png" >
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
      <img #title2 src="assets/img/2.png" >
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
      <img #title3 src="assets/img/3.png" >
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am getting an error, Cannot read property 'activeIndex' of undefined

Comment: Have you added `#mySlider` to the `ion-slides` element in your view?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes I have