# Access Object Instantiated From Another Class In TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**Background**

I have an `auth.service.ts` that when a user logs in it queries the `database` and returns any information we have on the user. The data is passed in to create a new `object` of `user`. It looks like this,

```
 user: User;
 this.user = res;
 console.log(this.user);
```

Outputs,

```
Object account_locked: false affiliate_owner: null business_phone: "8178966767" city_address: null contract: false created_on: null dob: "1984-03-05T06:00:00.000Z" email: "example@email.com" employee_owner: null fax_number: "1234567" first_name: "Nicholas" home_phone: "1234567" id: 7last_name: "theman" middle_name: "dude" mobile_phone: "1234567" ssn: "123456789" state_address: null street_address: null user_auth_level: 1 zip_address: null __proto__: Object
```

That being true, this...

```
console.log(this.user.email);
```

Which outputs `example@email.com`

**The Problem**

So when I go to another class and add `auth.service.ts` to it like this,

```
import { Auth }                    from './../services/auth.service';

constructor( private router: Router, private auth: Auth, private http: Http  ) { }
```

This outputs undefined,

```
ngOnInit() {
      console.log(this.auth.user);
     }
```

Also from the template I try and use interpolation {{auth.user.email}} which won't work either.

**Question**

How do I access the `object` `user` which is created in `auth.service.ts` from another class. In this case `profile.component.ts` and its template `profile.component.html`

Is this a problem of `inheritance`?

**Class Minimal**

```
    auth.service.ts

    export class Auth {
      lock = new Auth0Lock(myConfig.clientID, myConfig.domain, options, {});
      userProfile: Object;
      logreg: LogReg;
      user: User;
      constructor(private router: Router, private http: Http ) {
            // create users
            this.logreg = new LogReg(profile.email);   
            this.checkRegister(this.logreg).subscribe((res)=>{
                //do something with the response here
                this.user = res;
                console.log(this.user);
            });
    }
}
```

I want to access that object user here,

```
profile.component.ts

import { Auth }                    from './../services/auth.service';

@Component({
    providers: [ Auth ],
    templateUrl: './profile.component.html'
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor( private router: Router, private auth: Auth, private http: Http  ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      console.log(this.auth.user);
     }
}
```

Comment: please paste a minimal classes definitions to check this out.

Comment: Which class do you want to see?

Comment: the `auth.service.ts` that you want to access from another class like `User`.

Comment: I create the user in auth.service.ts im trying to pass it to profile.

Comment: Did you a `export class` in your `typescript` model?

Comment: yes I did not export class in auth service. I added more code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposed to have a class model `BaseObject` in the file `objects.ts` like

```
import * as P from "./protocols"

export class BaseObject implements P.ObjectProtocol {

/** 
     * Fill object by properties dictionary
     * @param properties Object Properties dictionary
    */
    public fill(properties:Object) {
        var self=this;
        for (var i in properties) {
            if (self.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                self[i]=properties[i];
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

you are going to export this object using `export class`.

Where ever you want to use this class you do

```
import {BaseObject} from "./objects"
export class MyObjectImpl extends BaseObject {
 //...
}
```

Regarding the issue of sharing the object instance you need a `singleton` pattern, take a look here: 
[Access key data across entire app in Angular 2 & Ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815478/access-key-data-across-entire-app-in-angular-2-ionic-2/36897300#36897300)

Comment: I am exporting the class  export class Auth {

Comment: Also if I use implments object dont I get more than just the one object I need which has been instantiated in it?

Comment: `implements OnInit ` what is `OnInit`? Should it be `implements Auth`?

Comment: @wuno you need to `new` that object first.

Comment: OnInit is built into angular 2

Comment: You do understand I can console.log the object from auth.service.ts just fine? My question is simply how do I make it accessible across all pages of the site. So every page a user navigates to I can provide information about their account.

Comment: ok now it's more clear, this is not a typescript heritance specific problem, your object is not visible outside the namespace.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129386/discussion-between-wuno-and-loretoparisi).