# How do you inject a custom service into another custom service?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I'm getting a `No Provider for FirebaseService` error even after bootstrapping the `FirebaseService` in the `bootstrap(app, [providers])` method.

I followed [Pascal's guide for injecting a service within a service](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html) and it worked when I injected the `Http` service with the `HTTP_PROVIDERS` bootstrapped, but I receive a `No providers for FirebaseService` error after changing it to my own service.

I can inject both providers individually by removing the injection of the `FirebaseService` just fine.
Even if I do `contructor(@Inject(FirebaseService) firebase: FirebaseService){}` it won't work, but my understanding is that adding the `@Injectable()` decorator should have the same effect.

**login-page.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {UserService} from '../../Services/user.service';
import {FirebaseService} from '../../services/firebase.service';
import {  UserModel } from '../../export';


@Component({
    moduleId: 'app/PAGES/login-page/',
    selector: 'login-page',
    templateUrl: 'login-page.html',
    styleUrls: ['login-page.css'],
    providers: [ UserService]
})
export class LoginPage {
    constructor(private userService: UserService) {}
    user:UserModel = new UserModel();
    hello: string = "You got yourself a login page, sir";

    dostuff() {

        console.log(this.user);
      //  this.userService.createUser(this.user);
    }
}
```

**main.ts**

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FirebaseService } from './SERVICES/firebase.service';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
     FirebaseService
]);
```

**UserService**

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import {FirebaseService} from './firebase.service';
import { UserModel } from '../export';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    constructor(private firebaseService: FirebaseService ) {}

    public createUser(user: UserModel): any {
        console.log(user);
   //     this.firebaseService.set(user)
    }

    public getUser(username: string): any {
   //     return this.firebaseService.get("users/" + username);
    }
}
```

**FirebaseService**

```
@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {

    public get(path: string): any {
      console.log(path);
    }

    public set(objectToSave: any) {
       console.log(objectToSave);
    }
}
```

Comment: For reference, the full repository is here: https://github.com/ChuckkNorris/Ng2RcTest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made plunk and it's working and inject firebase service into users service.

main.ts

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { App } from './app';
import { FirebaseService } from './firebase.service';

bootstrap(App, [
   FirebaseService
]);
```

app.ts

```
//our root app component
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import {UserService} from './user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [UserService],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>

    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    this.userService.createUser({h: 1});
    this.name = 'Angular2 (Release Candidate!)'
  }
}
```

user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import {FirebaseService} from './firebase.service';
import { UserModel } from '../export';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    constructor(private firebaseService: FirebaseService ) {}

    public createUser(user: UserModel): any {
      console.log(this.firebaseService)
      console.log(user);
   //     this.firebaseService.set(user)
    }

    public getUser(username: string): any {
   //     return this.firebaseService.get("users/" + username);
    }
}
```

firebase.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'
@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {

    public get(path: string): any {
      console.log(path);
    }

    public set(objectToSave: any) {
       console.log(objectToSave);
    }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/RLVT9dvfqH9W2BvE0qMG?p=preview

Comment: I think this answer is no longer valid as of Angular2 rc6

Comment: @PavelSapehin It's because this answer was written before the concept of modules was introduced. The new way to do it is to simply provide necessary services in the appropriate module (such as the root module) and a singleton service instance will be available throughout the application.

Comment: @Dyna, Thanks. It's not so obvious where to look at in the relatively large code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

I just learned that the import statement paths are case-sensitive.

I had `import {UserService} from '../../services/user.service';` while the directory was `../../SERVICES/user.service`.

Where's the facepalm emoji?

Comment: Dude, you saved my day. this is so silly, my folder was "Authentication" , so my import statement auto generated had "../Authentication/" , so changed it to "../authentication/" and everything worked. Maybe good solution is to not put caps in file names & folder names. I'm a newbie learning the tricks

Answer (score 0):

you are not inserting `UserService` in `main.ts`. try adding this as well :

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, provide } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router';
import { UxButton, UxText } from './export';
import { FirebaseService } from './SERVICES/firebase.service';
import { UserService } from './SERVICES/user.service';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
     FirebaseService,
     UserService     //<-- add this
    ,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES 
    ,ROUTER_PROVIDERS
    ,provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: UxButton, multi: true})
    ,provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: UxText, multi: true})
]);
```

your `login-page.ts` page is dependent on `UserService` so it needs to get bootstraped as well.

Comment: I already tried that with no success. I don't want a singleton instance for UserService, only for the Firebase instance. It's never been an issue before.