# Import Angular service1 into service2

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, dependency-injection

This is an Angular 6 and Firestore application. I'm trying to import service1 into service2 and getting the following error.

`compiler.js Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Service1`

I've read this [Medium article](https://medium.com/@MatheusCAS/injecting-a-service-into-another-service-in-angular-3b253df5c21) and this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33575456/angular2-services-how-to-inject-one-service-into-another-singletons/33582953) post, neither of which have provided insight.

Here is my code.

First, I import and list both services as providers in `app.module.ts`

```
#### app.module.ts ####

import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    AuthenticationService,
    UserService
  ]
  ...
})
```

And service1 `AuthenticationService` is this

```
#### authentication.service.ts ####

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from './models/user.model';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthenticationService {
  user: Observable<firebase.User>;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private router: Router,
              public userService: UserService ) {
                this.user = afAuth.authState;
              }
}
```

When I add service1 `AuthenticationService` to the constructor in service2 `UserService`, I get the compiler error listed above.

```
#### user.service.ts ####

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import {
  AngularFirestore,
  AngularFirestoreDocument,
  AngularFirestoreCollection
} from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from './models/user.model';
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class UserService {
  usersCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<User>;
  users: Observable<User[]>;
  username;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore, 
              private authserv: AuthenticationService) {
    this.usersCollection = this.afs.collection('users');
    this.users = this.usersCollection.valueChanges();

    this.authserv.user.subscribe(user => {
      if (user != null) {
        console.log('Id is: ' + user.uid);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Am I missing some code somewhere? Thank you.

Comment: That's not possible: you would need the UserService to create the AuthenticationService, but to create the UserService, you would need the AuthenticationService. So it's a chicken and egg problem. refactor your services to avoid such circular dependencies.

Comment: @JBNizet One dependency is okay, though, correct? AuthServ can be constructed with UserServ, yes? But it cannot work in reverse as well?

Comment: You can have UserService depend on AuthenticationService, or AuthenticationService depend on UserService, but not both, because that introduces a circular dependency: there is no way to create a service without also creating the other.

Comment: That is an answer to my question then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comments above, it is not possible to both

- Construct `service1` with `service2` as a dependency
- AND construct `service2` with `service1` as a dependency

You can do one or the other, but not both.